# why there is a delay in compiling framework7 vuejs cordova mobile app

Tags: cordova, vue.js, html-framework-7

i am creating a native mobile app with cordova using framework7 & vuejs.
everything work fine. but at starting of the app page  shows flattened for few seconds. then framework7 ui become visible.

at first it shows for 1-2 seconds:

[image]

then framework7 ui become visible.

[image]

someone help me

app.js

```
// Init F7 Vue Plugin
Vue.use(Framework7Vue)

// Init Page Components
Vue.component('page-about', {
  template: '#page-about'
})
Vue.component('page-form', {
  template: '#page-form'
})
Vue.component('page-dynamic-routing', {
  template: '#page-dynamic-routing'
})

// Init App
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // Init Framework7 by passing parameters here
  framework7: {
    root: '#app',
    material: true,
    swipePanel: 'left',
    animateNavBackIcon: true,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/about/',
    component: 'page-about'
  },
  {
    path: '/form/',
    component: 'page-form'
  },
  {
    path: '/dynamic-route/blog/:blogId/post/:postId/',
    component: 'page-dynamic-routing'
  }
    ],
  }
});
```

Comment: show some code or more hints...  (your computer maybe super slow?)

Comment: it contains demo scripts provided framework7 single page template